# Black screen after suspend - Toshiba NB515-SP020LL, GMA3600 graphics, Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: sleep, wakeup

Hi I'm trying to troubleshoot this and am [following these instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend) to help me out.

I'm getting a black screen after suspend and am using a Toshiba NB515-SP020LL with a GMA3600 graphics card. It has the latest BIOS. I am running 12.04

The graphics card isn't supported yet so I'm sure the problem is related to that. I don't mind since this is a netbook and high performance is not a priority. It'd just be nice to suspend the computer. :)

Any suggestions?

```
cat /proc/acpi/wakeup > wakeup

Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
ELAN      S4    *disabled  
USB0      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
USB1      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.1
USB2      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.2
USB3      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.3
USB7      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.7
RP01      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.0
PXSX      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:01:00.0
RP02      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.1
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:02:00.0
RP03      S4    *disabled  
PXSX      S4    *disabled  
RP04      S4    *disabled  
PXSX      S4    *disabled  
LID0      S4    *enabled
```

Comment: You could try [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsPoulsbo#Fix_suspend).

Comment: thanks! that specific suggestion didn't work but reading the pm-suspend man page is illuminating...

Comment: Hm..., to be honest, that didn't work on my netbook with GMA500 either. I had to do `sudo mv /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video /usr/lib/pm-utils/99video`, to solve exactly the same issue.

Comment: @mikewhatever I recommend posting that as an answer. Even if it's not what solved the OP's problem here, this is the best place to post it, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

To simply get suspend to work on this system I just added this line to the /etc/pm/config.d/gma500 configuration file:

```
ADD_PARAMETERS='--quirk-s3-mode'
```

I didn't have the file, or any other in that directory, so I created it.